# How can I append a div in jquery right after some text?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#timezone").html("sssssss");    
});
```

and html:

```
<p>lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum <div id="timezone"></div></p>
```

So far the result of that is:

```
lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum 

sssssss
```

but I want to have it:

```
lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum sssssss
```

how can I do it?
here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mwfpLqm7/1/

Comment: Instead of `div` use `span`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `span` instead of a `div`. You can't use divs inside a `p` element.

```
<p>lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum <span id="timezone"></span></p>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwfpLqm7/2/)**

Your browser outputs the html with the `div` outside of the `p` element because it is invalid HTML markup and anyway `div` is block element.